# Gradle gets stucked in Gradle Build Running state

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using `Windows 10` 64 bit and `Android Studio 1.5.1`. I haven't seen this problem earlier, but now it always stuck in `Gradle Build Running` state. I cannot abort this process, only kill with `Task Manager`. `:android:assembleRelease` is executing.

Comment: Close the Android Studio and try to build the project from command line with -i or -d flags, this will help you figure out which tasks slow down your build.

Comment: did you updated gradle version in warrper and build.gradle files?

Comment: @piotrek1543 : No, I haven't. Where should I update it exactly? This project is maybe one year old.

Comment: Check the message view for error messages. This is often caused by resource problems, like a missing translation when building a release apk.